# Javascript inside view in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to put some javascript inside a view. Basically I am having a play with the Recurly.js library.

Here is an example form: http://pastie.org/3142536

I have tried adding the JS to a partial: filename _recurly.js.erb

```
<%= render :partial => 'recurly.js', :locals => { :company => @company } %>
```

But its just outputting the JS to the page.

Is there a better way of doing this passing vars to JS for output and how can I get it to render the JS ?

Hope you can advise.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the function escape_javascript.

so your code should be:

`<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'recurly.js', :locals => { :company => @company }) %>`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
<%= raw(render :partial => 'recurly.js', ...) %>
```

Normally ERB will escape the output. Not sure if this is a good solution in the long run, even if it works, though.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use normal way of including javascript in your ERB view.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "filename_from_public_javascripts_folder" %>
```